# Log-concavity of a discrete random distribution

Tags: random-variable, hazard, logarithmic-series-distribution, log-concave

I'm working with a discrete distribution on the set of non-negative integers. The step-wise cumulative distribution function at any non-negative integer $i$ is
$$
F_i = \frac{2}{\log w}[\log(1+w^{i+1}) - \log(1+w^i)] -1
$$
where $w>1$ is a parameter.

Is it possible to prove that the rv with such a $F_i$ is log-concave? Or that its hazard rate function $p_i/(1-F_{i-1})$ is increasing with $i$ ($p_i$ being the probability mass function)?